# async long blocking method running in the UI thread after awaiting

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await

Its something around:

```
async Task foo(...)
{
   await Task.Yield();
   [long blocking I/O statements]
}
```

But the problem is that it still runs in the UI thread after the await. I made sure by getting the Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId for both the UI thread and the thread after await, and the UI thread is becoming not responsive.

So what should I do ? Should I use threads in the traditional way instead of relying  on async/await ? or is there a way to make it run in a new non-UI thread after the await ?

Comment: Can you wrap your 'long blocking I/O statements' into another awaitable, Task-returning method and await it?

Answer (score 4):

> But the problem is that it still runs in the UI thread after the await.

Yes, it would. That's half the whole point of `async`/`await` - that you get to come back to the right context.

It sounds like you really *should* start a new thread (or preferably, use a `Task<T>`) for the background operation, if you can't avoid the blocking IO. Then you can *use* the result in an async method:

```
async Task Foo(...)
{
    string result = await Task.Run(...);
    // Now update the UI with the result
}
```

Comment: i tried that and it worked, but i was updating UI elements from that thread (adding an item to a listview), and now "The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it." exception gets thrown.

Comment: I fixed the UI update exception by adding  this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() => before the UI update code. Hope I don't have more surprises today.

Comment: @xander: Why didn't you do it as per my suggestion? Do *just* the synchronous bit in another thread, and return to the UI thread when you've done that bit? You *can* use `Dispatcher.Invoke` of course, but the aim is for async/await to make that unnecessary in most scenarios.